# Convergence of martingales is a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I am reading the book "Introduction to Stochastic Integration (Second Edition)" by K.L. Chung and R.J. Williams. I have a question about the proof of Proposition 1.3 (on page 13) in that book. First, here are two definitions just so we are on the same page:

**Definition.** A collection $\{M_t, \mathcal{F}_t, t\in\mathbb{R}_+\}$ is called a *martingale* iff

1. $M_t\in L^1$ for each $t$,
2. $M_s = E(M_t\vert \mathcal{F}_s)$ for all $s<t$.

**Definition.** For $p\in [1,\infty)$, $M=\{M_t,\mathcal{F}_t, t\in\mathbb{R}_t\}$ is called an *$L^p$ martingale* iff it is a martingale and $M_t\in L^p$ for each $t$.

With these definitions in mind, the following is the statement and the proof of Proposition 1.3 (verbatim from the book):

**Proposition 1.3.** *Let $p\in [1,\infty)$. Suppose $\{M_t^n, \mathcal{F}_t, t\in\mathbb{R}_+\}$ is an $L^p$-martingale for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and for each $t$, $M_t^n$ converges in $L^p$ to $M_t$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. If $\mathcal{F}_0$ contains all of the $P$-null sets in $\mathcal{F}$, then $\{M_t, \mathcal{F}_t, t\in\mathbb{R}_+\}$ is an $L^p$-martingale.*

*Proof.* It suffices to verify condition (2) in the definition of a martingale. Fix $s<t$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$. For each $n$, $$M_s^n = E(M_t^n\vert\mathcal{F}_s).$$ The left hand side above converges in $L^p$ to $M_s$, by hypothesis, and by Proposition 1.2, the right side converges to $E(M_t\vert \mathcal{F}_s)$ in $L^p$. Hence $$M_s = E(M_t\vert \mathcal{F}_s)\quad\text{a.s.}$$ If $\mathcal{F}_0$ contains all of the $P$-null sets in $\mathcal{F}$, it follows that $M_s\in\mathcal{F}_s$ and then the a.s. above may be removed. QED.

I understand the first sentence (condition (1) follows since $L^1\subseteq L^p$ for $1\le p\le \infty$ holds in probability spaces). The second sentence holds by definition of a martingale. The first half of the third sentence is clear, and the second half of the third sentence is true directly from Proposition 1.2 in the book which is the following:

**Proposition 1.2.** *Suppose $\{X_n\}$ converges in $L^p$ to $X\in L^p$ for some $p\in [1,\infty)$. Then for any sub-$\sigma$-field $\mathcal{G}$ of $\mathcal{F}$, $\{E(X_n\vert\mathcal{G}\}$ converges in $L^p$ to $E(X\vert\mathcal{G})$.*

The fourth sentence doesn't make perfect sense to me. In particular, I do not understand exactly why
$$M_s^n\rightarrow M_s\text{ in } L^p\quad \text{and} \quad E(M_t^n\vert\mathcal{F}_s)\rightarrow E(M_t\vert\mathcal{F}_s)\text{ in } L^p\implies M_s = E(M_t\vert \mathcal{F}_s)\text{ a.s.}$$

I guess I do not really understand what the "a.s." is referring to or why we get that. Is it saying that for *any* representative of the equivalence class of $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable functions satisfying the martingale property, it only equals $M_s$ almost surely? (The weird thing to me is that any two representatives of $E(M_t\vert\mathcal{F}_s)$ only equal each other almost surely, so is the a.s. in the proof "more off" in some sense?) It seems to suggest that $M_s$ is not necessarily measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_s$, but I do not understand why $M_s$ may not be. On a similar note, $M_s^n$ is a representative of $E(M_t^n\vert\mathcal{F}_s)$, but the limit of $E(M_t^n\vert\mathcal{F}_s)$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable while the limit of $M_s^n$ isn't? Finally, I do not really understand the fifth sentence. Why would completing the filtration fix this?

I apologize for rambling, and I am not sure if I articulated my question(s) well or not, but the point is I do not know exactly what is going in in the fourth and fifth sentences. I want to understand it down to the last $\omega$, so clarity and details, rather than brevity and terseness, would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M_t^n\to M_t$ in $L^p$, there is a subsequence $(M_t^{n_k})$ s.t. $M_{t}^{n_k}\to M_t$ a.s. Since $\mathbb E[M_t^{n_k}\mid \mathcal F_s]\to \mathbb E[M_t\mid \mathcal F_s]$ in $L^p$, there is a subsequence $(\mathbb E[M_t^{n_{k_\ell}}\mid \mathcal F_s])$ s.t. $$\mathbb E[M_t^{n_{k_\ell}}\mid \mathcal F_s]\to \mathbb E[M_t\mid \mathcal F_s]\quad a.s.$$
Therefore $$M_s=\lim_{\ell\to \infty }M_{s}^{n_{k_\ell}}=\lim_{\ell\to \infty }\mathbb E[M_t^{n_{k_\ell}}\mid \mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[M_t\mid \mathcal F_s]\quad a.s.$$
and thus $M_s=\mathbb E[M_t\mid \mathcal F_s]$ a.s.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, is $M_s$ not necessarily $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable? The "a.s." quantifier seems too suggest this, or is there some other issue? Nevertheless, I want to understand how to remove the "a.s." quantifier. The proof indicates that a complete filtration does the trick.

Comment: You are welcome :-). Indeed, $M_s$ may be not $\mathcal F_s$ measurable if the filtration is not complete. In fact, if $f_n\to f$ in $(L_p,\mathcal M,\mu)$ and $(f_n)$ measurable, then $f$ is measurable in $\overline{\mathcal M}$ (the completion of $\mathcal M$) only.

Comment: Any insight there? $M_s^n$ is a representative of $E[M_t^n\vert\mathcal{F}_s]$, yet the a.s. limit of $M_s^n$ (along a subsequence) may not be $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable, but the a.s. limit of $E[M_t^n\vert\mathcal{F}_s]$ (along a subsequence) is $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable? Can you explain how completing the filtration will solve this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh thank you for the addition to your comment. I assume it is a standard result in measure theory, and I am happy with that. But still I lack intuition regarding my first question.

Comment: In both case, the limit of $\mathbb E[M_t^n\mid \mathcal F_s]$ and $M_s^n$ may be not measurable if $\mathcal F_s$ is not complete. Just a very easy example : take any function $f$ that is Lebesgue measurable, integrable, but not a Borel function. By approximation theorem, there is a sequence $(f_n)$ of $\mathcal C^\infty $ function that converges almost everywhere to $f$. You have that $(f_n)$ is a sequence of Borel function, but $f$ is not a Borel function. Therefore, to insure that the limit is measurable, the $\sigma -$algebra must be complete.

Comment: Is the point the following? We know that there exists a subsequence of $E[M_t^n\vert \mathcal{F}_s]$ converging to $E[M_t\vert \mathcal{F}_s]$, so the a.s. limit here is indeed $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable. But, all we know about $M_s$ is that it is the $L^p$ limit of $M_s^n$ and do not know a priori if it is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable? So the point is that we have two a.s. limits here. One (i.e., $E[M_t\vert\mathcal{F}_s)$ is measurable, but the other (i.e., $M_t$) is not a priori measurable. So the choice in a subsequence may result in either a measurable function or a non-measurable one?

Comment: Notice that you also have a subsequence of $(M_t^n)$ that converges almost surely to $M_t$. But this is really not the point ! Let $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ a measure space, and let $f_n:X\to \mathbb R$ measurable for all $n$. Suppose that there is $f:X\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x$ (so even stronger than almost everywhere). Then $f$ is measurable only whenever $\mathcal M$ is complete (if $\mathcal M$ is not complete, you can always find a non measurable copy of $f$).

Comment: Right, the subsequence is not really the point. With that said, does my above comment make sense? For that, it seems like one sub-sequential limit is measurable, but another sub-sequential limit is not measurable. By non-measurable copy do you mean the following: If $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, there is a Borel measurable function (but not Lebesgue measurable) that differs from $f$ on a Lebesgue measure-zero set?

Comment: I mean : if $\mathcal M$ is not complete and $f$ is $\mathcal M-$measurable, there is a non measurable function $g$ s.t. $f=g$ almost everywhere. In your previous comment, notice that $\mathbb E[M_t\mid \mathcal F_s]$ is not defined if $M_t$ is not $\mathcal F_t$ measurable.

Comment: Sorry for belaboring the point, but I am still confused about the following. Going back, we have an underlying filtered prob. space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_t\}, P)$. We have $M_s^n = E[M_t^n\vert\mathcal{F}_s]$. We know $M_t$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable (it being in $L^p$). So, $E[M_t\vert\mathcal{F}_s]$ is well-defined, and, by def., $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable. But, $M_s$ is not guaranteed to be $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. Yet $M_s$ is a sub-sequential a.s. limit of $M_s^n$, but $E[M_t\vert\mathcal{F}_s]$ is the sub-sequential a.s. limit of $M_s^n$ along a different subseq. Right?

Comment: To add onto the previous comment, I am just trying to reconcile how in the pre-limit $M_s^n$ and $E[M_t^n\vert\mathcal{F}_s]$ are the same, yet in the limit they are different in the sense that one is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable, while one isn't. And the reason seems to be that $M_s$ is not a priori $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable (it is just $\mathcal{F}$-measurable), while, by definition $E[M_t\vert\mathcal{F}_s]$, is by definition $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable. Taking subsequences was a nice trick to get the result, and the "a.s." is really $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P)$-a.s. That's my understanding.

Comment: Indeed, if $M_t$ is $\mathcal F-$measurable, then $\mathbb E[M_t\mid \mathcal F_s]$ is $\mathcal F_s-$measurable. At the end, this $\mathcal F_s$measurability of $M_s$ is really a minor problem since you can always complete a $\sigma -$algebra so that every set of measure $0$ are measurable. For your other question : take $f_n=\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1]}=g_n$. $f_n\to 0=f$ in $L^1$ and $g_n\to \boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]}=g$ in $L^1$. So, there are subsequence $f_{n_k}$ and $g_{n_k}$ that converges to $f$ and $g$ a.s. At the end $f_n=g_n$ for all $n$, but $f=g$ a.s. only.

Comment: Great, that makes sense. Trying to understand all the details (even the minor ones). This helped a lot.